# timedatectl set-timezone Access denied

Tags: raspbian-stretch, raspbian-lite

I get error when trying to set time:

```
$ sudo timedatectl set-timezone America/New_York   
Failed to set time zone: Access denied
```

This is on an almost pristine stretch lite image. I noticed

```
$ ls -lad /etc  
drwxr-xr-x 92 pi pi 4096 Mar 12 12:16 /etc
```

Shouldn't `/etc` be owned by **root**?
Is there something that changed ownership to pi?

I tried

```
sudo chown root /etc
```

and that seemed to fix this issue, but did I break something else?
Is this a bug with the original OS image?

Comment: Whatever you've done your system is broken. /etc and most of the "system" files should be root:root for owner and group. There's nothing sensible you can do apart from creating a fresh SDCard with Raspbian then moving your data & programs from the broken card.

Comment: in my `/etc` - all files are owned by root ... all but 7 have group ownership of root (2 of which you're unlikely to have) ... so, `chown root` probably fixed most of the issue, but there's still the `group` that needs to be fixed

Comment: Thanks. I had a specific list of things I installed carefully, but somewhere  /etc got changed.

Answer (score 2):

Minutes after starting the new image, I used

```
cd /  
sudo tar -xf /home/pi/files.tar.gz
```

to put a few files at needed places. I should have used

```
sudo tar --no-same-owner -xf /home/pi/files.tar.gz
```

since tar changed ownership of directories it did not create.

--same-owner is a tar default when run as superuser, and the tar was created from pi-owned directories.

Answer (score 0):

Your **Raspbian Stretch Lite** installation cannot be pristine. I have just used a virgin installation of [Raspbian Stretch Lite 2018-11-13](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/). It shows that `/etc` belongs to user **root** and group **root**.

There is another weird thing with your installation. Using `sudo` to execute commands run them with superuser **root** and has no restrictions, particular running commands belonging to other users. I cannot see why **root** should fail to execute `timedatectl` only why `/etc` has user:group `pi:pi`.

I suggest to download [Raspbian Stretch Lite 2018-11-13](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/), compare the checksum and either [using etcher to flash the image](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/) or use

```
unzip -p 2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch.zip | sudo dd of=/dev/sdX bs=4M conv=fsync
```

on a Linux machine to flash the image to the SD Card.

Comment: Thanks. I will start with a new image. I only installed a few things, but something must have affected /etc.

Comment: @Codemeister If the answer help you a bit it would be nice if you could accept it. This will finish the question and show other users that it has a solution.